# .NET Framework, .NET Core, .NET Native, DNX, Core CLR, CIL, PCL - simple explain?

Tags: .net, cil, dnx, coreclr

Today's .NET world looks too complex. Could somebody give a short explain of these terms?

There is some info in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29609993/difference-between-net-framework-4-6-net-native-and-net-core) thread, but it not discovers a complete picture.

[image]

Comment: Explain the entire .NET ecosystem? That's **far** too broad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- NET Framework: full blown Framework for running managed solutions in the Windows Ecosystem
- NET Core: reduced set of NET Framework, that is cross-platform and supports applications for various OSes and CPUs
- NET Native: Framework that converts C# to C++ like code and is used for developing Windows 10 universal apps
- DNX: NET Execution Environment - contains the code required to bootstrap and run an application, including the compilation system, SDK tools, and the native CLR hosts (basically cross-platform developing mechanisms)
- Core CLR: .NET Core runtime: framework supporting the NET Core
- CIL: intermediate representation of the C# code (similar to Java bytecode) that will be further translated into assembly code by the JIT compiler
- PCL: Portable Class Library - class library for Universal apps

Answer (score 3):

**.NET framework**- is basically a programming infrastructure created by Microsoft for building, deploying, and running applications and services that use .NET technologies, such as desktop applications and Web services.
**.NET core**- is the NET Core is the small optimized runtime that is the basis of ASP.NET Core 5.
**.NET native**-  is a precompilation technology for building Universal Windows apps in Visual-  Studio 2015
**DNX**- Dot Net Execution environment  is a new .NET SDK that is designed to allow development and execution across multiple platforms.
**core CLR**- is basically a .NET core runtime which includes the garbage collector .
**CIL**- ***C Intermediate Language*** is the lowest-level human-readable programming language is a simplified transformation of C used for further analysis
**PCL**- ***Portable Class Libraries***  enables .NET developers to write and build managed assemblies that work on more than one .NET Framework platform

Comment: daumie, thank you! Your answer is very useful, it contains facts missed in accepted one.

Comment: Welcome @AsValeO I got a clearer underesatanding from the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

This [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zw4w595w(v=vs.110).aspx) from MSDN would be better.

Comment: "Link only" answers tend to be frowned upon here. An answer should be able to stand on its own merits, even if the link is no longer available (The quick test is, read the *text* of the answer. Does it contain enough information to give the OP some information without knowing which, if any, of the words are actually links - in this case, no, it doesn't. You don't even tell us the *title* of the page you're linking to)