# Why is net46 denoted as a desktop framework?

Tags: .net-core

In relation to .NET Core I came across this sentence:

> The “netcoreapp1.0” is the new designation for dxcore apps. You could also add “net46” or “dnx46” to use the desktop .NET framework"

See this page: https://wildermuth.com/2016/05/13/Getting-Ready-for-ASP-NET-Core-RC2

Can anybody explain what is meant by the "desktop .NET framework" in this context? Why does it have anything to do with "desktop"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between .NET Framework 4.6, .Net Native and .Net Core](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29609993/difference-between-net-framework-4-6-net-native-and-net-core)

Comment: In short, because the net46 framework contains the WinForms and WPF libraries/APIs to build traditional desktop applications.  These are not available .Net Core because they are not cross-platform.

Comment: .NET 4.6 is the version number of the framework that can only be installed on a desktop class machine.  The kind of machine you need to run VS.  It is the big one.  .NETCore is the small one, originally targeted for mobile devices, it started life as the Compact Framework.

Comment: Thx for these comments. It makes more sense now. The designation is still slightly misleading as the net46 would also be used for building web applications with dependencies to .NET framework 46 such as EntityFramework 6.