# Using Active Directory Authentication for Azure SQL server in .Net Core App 1.1

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, azure, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-1.1

I want to connect to my Azure SQL server using Azure Active Directory Authentication in a .Net Core App 1.1 .

On using a connection string similar to the following connection string:

```
Data Source=n9lxnyuzhv.database.windows.net; Authentication=Active Directory Integrated; Initial Catalog=testdb;
```

I get this exception:

```
System.ArgumentException: 'Keyword not supported: 'authentication'.'
```

I understand that AAD Auth is available for SQL servers in .Net Framework 4.6 and above. Is it possible to connect to server through AAD in .Net Core Apps. If so, how?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, .Net Core does not support for Microsoft Active Directory Authentication Library for Microsoft SQL Server. Please refer to this [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217321-sql-database/suggestions/17836318-add-net-core-support-for-microsoft-active-directo).

With the Active Directory Admin set for the Azure SQL Server you are able to login to the SQL server with SQL Server Management Studio. On all client machines, from which your applications or users connect to Azure SQL Database or Azure SQL Data Warehouse using Azure Active Directory  users / applications, you must install the following software:

- .NET Framework 4.6 or later
- Azure Active Directory Authentication Library for SQL Server
  (ADALSQL.DLL) is available in multiple languages (both x86 and amd64)

This [blog](https://msftplayground.com/2017/04/part-1-azure-sql-database-with-azure-active-directory-authentication/) maybe helpful.

Comment: adalsql.dll is already present in the system folder of my machine. I am able to connect to SQL server using Azure AD through .Net Framework 4.6 application. However the .Net Core 1.1 application gives me the above exception.

Comment: @M_coder According to the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication#connecting-using-azure-ad-identities). `SQL Server 2016 Management Studio and SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio 2015 (version 14.0.60311.1April 2016 or later) support Azure Active Directory authentication. (Azure AD authentication is supported by the .NET Framework Data Provider for SqlServer; at least version .NET Framework 4.6). `

Comment: @M_coder It seems that `Azure Active Directory Authentication for authentication with SQL Database` does not support .Net Core Apps.

Comment: @M_coder Please refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29609993/difference-between-net-framework-4-6-net-native-and-net-core). `NET Core on the other hand is a subset of .NET Framework 4.6 which is mainly optimized for multi-platform and cloud deployments`. If you want to use Azure AD authentication for SQL you should use .NET framework 4.6.

Comment: This is what I had initially feared that it might not yet be supported in .Net Core apps. Thanks for the prompt response.

Comment: @M_coder For now, it is not possible. Please refer to this [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217321-sql-database/suggestions/17836318-add-net-core-support-for-microsoft-active-directo) or the [link](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/8807).

Comment: Zombie post, but it now looks like .NET Core 2.2 has this feature available.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-core-2-2#data